# Param value declaration in a pig script through shell script IF condition

Tags: bash, shell, apache-pig

I am trying to execute a pig script by declaring one of the param through shell script. This shell script contains IF condition.

```
%DECLARE dataSet `if [ $condition == true ]; then echo "A"; else echo "B"; fi`;

start = LOAD 'test.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
A = FOREACH start GENERATE $0,$1,$2,$3,$4;
B = FILTER A BY ($0==1);
C = FOREACH $dataSet GENERATE $0,$1,$2,$3,$4;
DUMP C;
```

But  it is throwing an error as 'Error executing shell command'.  When I execute the same shell script though command line, it works fine. Tried with different syntax of if condition but no success. 
If we consider the simple shell script without IF condition, it works fine.

Could you please help me to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure it'll solve your problem but you shouldn't be using `==` inside `[` - use `=` to compare strings. You should also wrap `$condition` in double quotes.

Comment: try using [[ ]] brackets in IF

Comment: Thank you for helping. Tried your suggestions but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for all your help. @vad solutions works fine if it is only sh. As i understood, **currently PIG doesn't support complex shell script(like IF condition) when we do param declaration.** During this
investigation time, I considered another approach suggested by my friend that solved the actual problem.

Instead of passing "true" or "false" value to the "$condition" variable, am passing actual data set name.

Modified script is,

```
%DECLARE dataSet `echo $condition`; 

--where value for $condition is A or B. 
--earlier it was true or false

start = LOAD 'test.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
A = FOREACH start GENERATE $0,$1,$2,$3,$4;
B = FILTER A BY ($0==1);
C = FOREACH $dataSet GENERATE $0,$1,$2,$3,$4;
DUMP C;
```

It is working fine as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve by running `bash -c "<script>"`:

```
%DECLARE dataSet `bash -c "if [ $condition == true ]; then echo A; else echo B; fi"`;

start = LOAD 'test.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
A = FOREACH start GENERATE $0,$1,$2,$3,$4;
B = FILTER A BY ($0==1);
C = FOREACH $dataSet GENERATE $0,$1,$2,$3,$4;
DUMP C;
```

Comment: What do you mean by “it's not a shell script that you run, but a command”? What you wrote (`bash -c "…"`) is in shell syntax. How is the string inside the backticks parsed?

Comment: you don't need a shell to run commands, right? I don't know how it's parsed, there can be a parser somewhere.

Comment: You don't need a shell to run commands, but they have to be supplied in the form of a path to a program and a list of arguments: the [OS primitive](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) takes a list of strings as arguments, not a single string. If there's any parsing going on, such as here with the quotes around the second argument to `bash`, that's a shell doing it.

Comment: Is the fact that there is a shell or not the point? I don't think so. I can change the intro of the response if you prefer, but the fact is that it works!

Comment: What could make it work is ensuring that `[ $condition == true ]` is parsed by a bash, as opposed to sh (which may or may not be sh). But [the asker has indicated that this isn't the problem, or not the only problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489603/param-value-declaration-in-a-pig-script-through-shell-script-if-condition/27530854#comment43413612_27490361).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Pig, but I suspect that like any other program it invokes `sh` to run external shell commands.

```
if [ $condition == true ]; then echo "A"; else echo "B"; fi
```

is not valid sh syntax: the `==` operator is a bash extension. Try

```
if [ "$condition" = true ]; then echo "A"; else echo "B"; fi
```

The double quotes around `$condition` may or may not be necessary in your case but [they are often necessary so get into the habit of using them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters). In unix shells (bash or sh), `"$condition"` means “the value of the variable `condition`” whereas `$condition` means “take the value of the variable `condition`, split it into words and treat each word as a glob pattern”; unless you want all of that to happen, use double quotes.

You can read the [dash](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dash.1.html) or [posh](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/posh.1.html) manual to see what features are supported in plain `sh`. There are several implementations of `sh` around; dash is a common one, posh less so but it is pretty close to the largest common denominator. You can read the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/idx/shell.html) if you prefer, but it's even less readable than man pages.

Comment: Thank you for helping. Tried all the examples, suggestions above. But no success. <br>   %DECLARE dataSet `if [ "$condition" = "true" ]; then echo "A"; else echo "B"; fi`